# I2C Drivers on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile, i2c

I'd like to access I2C drivers on my Samsung S3 GT19300 from an Android application.

Do I need to root the device to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the device must be rooted in order to access the I2C drivers.